# Using C++11 auto keyword to declare two (or more) variables

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, auto

I have code like this:

```
template<class ListItem>
static void printList(QList<ListItem>* list)
{
    for (auto i = list->size() - 1, j = -1; i >= 0; --i) {
        std::cout << i << ", " << j << ": " << list->at(i) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I compile it with g++ 6.2.1 I get the following compiler output:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void printList(QList<T>*)’:
test.cpp:10:7: error: inconsistent deduction for ‘auto’: ‘auto’ and then ‘int’
  for (auto i = list->size() - 1, j = -1; i >= 0; --i) {
       ^~~~
```

I'd understand this, if variables had different types like `auto i = 0.0, j = 0;`, but in this case list is a pointer to QList and its size() method returns `int`, `-1` on its own should be `int`, too. The error message is a bit strange as well.

Variables `i` and `j` are only needed in this loop and I'd like to declare them as loop parameters. It's not hard to type `int` instead of auto, but I'd like to know: is `auto` not supposed to be used for declaring multiple variables in one go, or I am missing something here and it really is erroneous code, or maybe it is the compiler's bug?

P.S. Looks like using a template function is the critical part here, factoring the loop out of the template does not produce errors. So, more like a bug in the compiler?

[Live demo - minimal code](https://godbolt.org/g/6zAhEl)

Comment: [mcve], please. You write that `modelList` is a `QList`, but your compiler obviously disagrees, so I'd like to be able to tell which one is wrong. Which I can't do without seeing the same code the compiler does.

Comment: It's a curious use at least. Auto is meant for a single parameter auto-determination based on its initialization expression, and multiple parameters could derive to different types.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc1ca01afe50201a working fine with C++11, sure `modelList` is a `QList`?

Comment: @dascandy, It's entirely legal. And moreover, `auto val = make_val(), *pval = &val;` is quite natural.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy What does it do then when they have subtly different types, such as size_t and int? Or possibly-the-same types, such as uint32_t and unsigned long?

Comment: @dascandy it [errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a478963372dc6f98).

Comment: @dascandy, The requirement is that `auto` must be deduced to the same type.

Comment: The error implies that the deduced types for `i` and `j` don't match, hence `size()` does not return `int`... But `QList::size` does return an `int`. There's something fishy here

Comment: Yep, and trhis 'fishy' is using a template function. Do I just edit original post and provide this 'minimal' and 'complete' code sample?

Comment: Does it work if you change from `static void printList(QList<ListItem>* list)` to `static void printList(QList<std::string>* list)`?

Comment: Ah, now that there's the full code, it makes sense. The compiler cannot deduce the type of `list->size()` because `list` depends on template arguments. Remember, `QList<ListItem>` may be specialized so that `list->size()` may return a type other than `int`.

Comment: @Tommy Andersen: Well, yes. If I also change the call in main to `printList<std::string>(&list);`, since ListItem becomes 'orphan' (eg completely unused) and compiler can't deduce its type anymore.

Comment: It is due to compiletime determination of the type then, but it puzzles me since `size()` of `QList` is (at least in the source I found) written so it always returns `int`.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: Template is instantiated at the point of using it, isn't it? `QList`'s method `size()` is not item type dependent, declared to always return `int`.

Comment: @drongo, Instantiated, yes. But some restrictions are checked generically, before instantiation. Try removing all uses of your `printList`: the diagnostic should remain.

Comment: @drongo: Please specify: Whether function `printList` is called from anywhere in code or just the definition is specified in code?

Comment: @sameerkn I edited the question to remove irrelevant parts. In the original, `printList` is called with an argument of type `QList<std::string>`.

Comment: The bug was fixed for version 6.4. It also helped uncover more issues (see my update below) so bringing this up was an excellent idea. cc @Oktalist

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug in GCC.

According to [dcl.spec.auto]/1:

> The `auto` and `decltype(auto)` *type-speciﬁers* are used to designate
>   a placeholder type that will be replaced later by deduction from an
>   initializer. [...]

The rules for template argument deduction never deduce a type to be `auto`. The purpose of deduction in this case is actually to *replace* `auto` with a deduced type.

In the example, `list` has a dependent type (it depends on the template parameter `ListItem`), so the expression `list->size() - 1` also has a dependent type, which makes the type of `i` also dependent, which means it will only be resolved upon instantiation of the function template `printList`. Only then can the other semantic constraints related to that declaration be checked.

According to [temp.res]/8:

> Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template
>   to be checked. The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> [... long list of cases of which none applies here ...]
>
> Otherwise, **no diagnostic shall be issued for a template for which a
>   valid specialization can be generated**. [ *Note:* If a template is
>   instantiated, errors will be diagnosed according to the other rules in
>   this Standard. Exactly when these errors are diagnosed is a quality of
>   implementation issue. *— end note* ]

(emphasis mine)

GCC is wrong to issue that error when analyzing the definition of the template `printList`, since clearly valid specializations of the template can be generated. In fact, if `QList` doesn't have any specializations for which `size()` returns something else than `int`, the declaration for `i` and `j` will be valid in all instantiations of `printList`.

---

All quotes are from [N4606](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf), the (almost) current working draft, but the relevant parts of the quotes above haven't changed since C++14.

---

Update: [Confirmed as a regression](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78693) in GCC 6 / 7. Thanks to [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) for the bug report.

Update: The original bug ([78693](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78693)) was fixed for the upcoming 6.4 and 7.0 releases. It also uncovered some other issues with the way GCC handles such constructs, resulting in two other bug reports: [79009](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79009) and [79013](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79013).

Comment: I didn't understand the relationship between the question and your last quote. What is what isn't gcc reporting?

Comment: @Peregring-lk GCC issues an error when analyzing the function template `printList` (or `foo` in the minimal example added at the end of the question). The last quote indicates that this is incorrect: instantiating, for example, `printList<std::string>` (or `foo<int>`), results in a perfectly valid and consistent declaration for `i` and `j`, so GCC shouldn't issue that error on the template definition. Trying to instantiate `foo<long>` should trigger an error, but for that specialization; the definition of the template `foo` itself is valid.

Comment: @bogdan Ok, though I don't know why but I'm still not fully getting it. I think is just something so obvious in short (if it works, nothing must be reported), that I'm still searching for something else; after all, it's a quote of the standard about template instantiations. It cannot be something obvious.

Comment: @T.C., can you see if the problem discussed in this question also a bug: [Why compilation fails when a template parameter name matches an inner class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41280133/514235). I am unable to register an account in gcc and hence raise this bug. See if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in my comment to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40852055/514235), I agree with the analysis you have presented.
Simplest form of the problem ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)):

```
template<class T>
void foo (T t) {
  auto i = t, j = 1; // error: inconsistent deduction for ‘auto’: ‘auto’ and then ‘int’
}    
int main () {}
```

In case of templates, compiler in its 1st stage, checks the basic syntax without instantiating it. In our case, we are never invoking `foo()` anyways.

Now, in above example, the `decltype(auto)` for `i` is still `auto`, because the dependent type `T` is not known. However, `j` is surely `int`. 
Hence, the **compiler error makes sense**. Present behavior (G++ >= 6), may or may not be a bug. It depends on what do we expect from the compiler. :-)

However, this error cannot be condemned. Here is the supporting standard quote from [C++17 draft](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf):

> 7.1.7.4.1  Placeholder type deduction
>
> <sup>4</sup> **If the placeholder is the auto type-specifier, the deduced type T replacing T is determined using the rules for template argument deduction**. Obtain P from T by replacing the occurrences of auto with either a new invented
>   type template parameter U

The same thing is present in [C++14 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) as 7.1.6.4 / 7.

---

**Why is this error being reported in the first template check itself?**

We may rightly argue that, why the compiler is being so "pedantic" in the first syntax check itself. Since, we are not instantiating, then shouldn't it be ok! Even if we instantiate, shouldn't it give error only for the problematic calls!
That's what g++-5 does. Why did they bother to change it?

I think, it's a valid argument. With g++-5, if I call:

```
foo(1);  // ok
foo(1.0); // error reported inside `foo()`, referencing this line
```

Then compiler correctly reports the error and its hierarchy when `i` and `j` are of different types.

Comment: That would be my concern, actually: isn't the first stage supposed to be just that, **basic syntax check**? `<type> <variable> <=> <variable> <,> <variable> <=> <literal> <;>` is perfectly valid.

Comment: What in the standard determines how much the compiler should or can do as far as actual translating goes, when parsing the template prior to instantiation?

Comment: @TheVee, I am not sure. Your point is valid as well. I have updated my answer considering that.

Comment: @TheVee the compiler can do full semantic checking of statements that don't depend on template parameters. GCC and Clang will diagnose `int x = "string literal";` in the first stage, for example.

Comment: I think this is one of those rare cases where MS made a good call in wandering away from the herd.  They really don't parse the contents of the templated function at all until it's instantiated.  That gets around all sorts of warnings and errors, leaving just those that actually apply where it's instantiated.  The downside, of course, is that failing to instantiate the function anywhere (e.g. in your test suite) means that a function which is compile-time broken may go unnoticed until, say, your middleware API is released and someone in the wild tries to use it.

Comment: @AikenDrum It also breaks the name lookup rules and it means that the compiler wastes time reinstantiating code that is invariant across all instantiations of a given template. When is it ever a good idea to postpone inevitable errors?

Answer (score 1):

I'll summerise the information received on the topic then.

The issue in the example code is in using a template function.
Compiler does a generic check of a template first without instantiating it, this means that types, that are template arguments (and types that depend on them, like other templates) are not known, and `auto` if it depends on those unknown types is deduced into `auto` again (or not deduced into some concrete type). It never appeared to me that even after deduction `auto` can still be `auto`. Now original compiler error text makes perfect sense: variable `j` is deduced to be of type `int`, but variable `i` is still `auto` after deduction. Since `auto` and `int` are different types, compiler generates the error.

Comment: The question remains, whether this is a compiler bug, defect in the standard, or conformant behaviour. GCC 4, GCC 5, and all Clang versions happily compile the code without error. Only GCC >= 6 is affected.

Comment: I agree with the analysis. If GCC >= 6 is not buggy, then this answer seems logical.

Comment: In what universe is this not a compiler bug? There's nothing to deduce when the type is dependent.

Comment: `auto` is not a type, I think rather gcc reporting `auto` means that gcc has not deduced the type yet.