# hiding of template parameter of member template

Tags: c++, templates, standards, name-lookup

from [temp.local](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#temp.local-7) :

> In the definition of a member of a class template that appears outside
>   of the class template definition, the name of a member of the class
>   template hides the name of a template-parameter of any enclosing class
>   templates (**but not a template-parameter of the member if the member is
>   a class or function template**).
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct A {
>   struct B { /* ... */ };
>   typedef void C;
>   void f();
>   template<class U> void g(U);
> };
>
> template<class B> void A<B>::f() {
>   B b;              // A's B, not the template parameter
> }
>
> template<class B> template<class C> void A<B>::g(C) {
>   B b;              // A's B, not the template parameter
>   C c;              // the template parameter C, not A's C
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

the problem is that, each compiler, that i have tried ( g++, vc, icc, clang ), treats C in `A<B>::g(C)` as A's member name and doesn't compile that example.

Is this a common bug.?

Comment: Well, given that "each compiler" that you tried did that, I can't think of any better definition of "common". That's a rather persuasive argument for describing this as a "common" compiler bug.

Comment: i meant "common to all compilers, that i have tried".

Comment: There aren't really that many C++ compilers around. Looks like you've pretty much named them all. They don't exactly grow on trees, you know... It's safe to ignore historical compilers...

Comment: Related: [Why compilation fails when a template parameter name matches an inner class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41280133/514235)

Comment: `template<class B> template<class C> void A<B>::g(C)` is the body definition for method member of `struct A`. So, you better not try to make the compiler/developer confuse. In that case, the name of parameter still be hidden. Example, you can call: 
`struct A<int> a; a.g<char>(1);`

Answer (score 1):

While the link you gave appears to be a draft and explicitly states it is not a part of any standard (http://eel.is/c++draft/), this particular clause in the draft appears to be identical to ISO C++ 14.6.1, paragraph 7.

So it does indeed seem to be either a common compiler bug or a clause that conflicts with and lost out to other clauses. I verified the example doesn't compile on MacOS Clang v802.0.42). Since you say all the major compilers emit errors here, I would suspect this clause is not reasonable to implement due to conflicts with some other clause(s).

EDIT: I also found a discussion within the standards community [here](ftp://std.dkuug.dk/JTC1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#459) related to this topic. The depth with which it gets discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/comp.lang.c++.moderated/iWvVYV8BNI8/PY12lLeoiVMJ) suggests to me that this rule is contentious and may even be changed.